# The local variable may not have been initialized constructor/method

Tags: java, variables, methods, constructor, local

Code is nowhere near done but I'm basically stuck at this until I can move any further. Keep getting a local variable may not have been initialized on theirPhone.. If I move the constructor passed the try catch I get an error on the try catch, if I leave it the way it is I get the error at theirPhone.getAreaCode(phoneNumber); any help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomerTelephone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomerTelephone theirPhone;
        String phoneNumber = "407 407 4074";

        try {
            theirPhone = new CustomerTelephone(phoneNumber);
        } catch (InvalidTelephoneException ite) {
            System.out.println("Invalid telephone number format.");
        }

        theirPhone.getAreaCode(phoneNumber);

    }

    public CustomerTelephone(String telephone) throws InvalidTelephoneException {
        if (telephone.length() != 12) {
            throw new InvalidTelephoneException(
                "The phone number was entered incorrectly.");
        }
    }

    public String getAreaCode(String phoneNumber) {
        String goBack;
        String[] teleArray = phoneNumber.split("(?!^)");
        goBack = teleArray[0 - 2];

        return goBack;
    }

    public String getExchange(String phoneNumber) {
        String goBack = null;

        return goBack;
    }

    public String getLocalNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        String goBack = null;

        return goBack;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix:  Initialize the reference to null:

```
CustomerTelephone theirPhone = null;
```

Better fix: Initialize the variable and move the reference to that variable into the try block.  Thus if an exception is thrown in your try block, then you avoid a subsequent NullPointer exception.

```
CustomerTelephone theirPhone = null;
 ...
try {
    theirPhone = new CustomerTelephone(phoneNumber);
    theirPhone.getAreaCode(phoneNumber);
} catch {
...
}
```

Comment: This will work, but will anyway cause `NullPointerException` if `InvalidTelephoneException` is thrown in `try` block :)

Comment: Now how would I go about catching the NullPointerException?

Comment: Fair point about the NPE.  I have updated my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it makes sense: compiler tells you that if `InvalidTelephoneException` is thrown in `try` block, then execution goes to `catch` block, `System.out.println` prints error message to console and goes further to `theirPhone.getAreaCode(phoneNumber)` BUT at this point `theirPhone` is `null` so `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

I would recommend to add `return;` statement after `Systen.out.println` line so that program terminates in case of invalid phone number format.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `theirPhone` is not necessarily initialized in the main method in the try block that follows it (the compiler will assume that there is a chance of failure at any point in the block). Try giving the variable a default value or null when it is declared.